How long can yuccas go without direct sunlight?
I have 2 banana yuccas I've been babying in pots. I have a spot on a more or less north-facing slope that I'm thinking of putting them, and it's unfortunately not ideal because in the (San Diego) winter time, it gets only a modicum of direct sunlight at best because of the slope the row of giant bird-of-paradise at the top. It stays like that for essentially the whole winter, but by summertime it gets plenty of sun all day.
Can these things survive a whole winter like that? Otherwise, I have a slightly sunnier slope where I can place them, but I'm saving that for the opuntias.

Hi Thesaurus Rex, a picture would help us visualize the site

@kevinskio Sure, here's an Imgur album. https://imgur.com/a/2rqLZ1u I took those pictures at 6:30 AM here, but it gives an example of the light level during most of winter.

Of course, desert plants are used to maximum sun, but they should do great in open North light, too. If not, can you move them later?

Banana yuccas (Yucca baccata) are quite hardy and can tolerate a range of conditions, including partial shade. However, they do prefer full sun whenever possible. In San Diego's mild climate, your banana yuccas should be able to survive the winter in the spot you described, especially if they receive plenty of sunlight during the summer months.
Since your plants will receive ample sunlight in the summer, they can store up energy during that time to sustain them through the winter months when they receive less direct sunlight. Additionally, the slope you mentioned might still allow for some indirect sunlight, which can also contribute to their survival.

Thanks! I ended up planting them by the northeast-facing slope by my hellstrip. I think they'd benefit more there.
